# Mutable Arc in Rust

Tags: rust

Earlier I had a `Sync + Send` trait `SyncMessenger`:

```
trait Messenger {
    fn send_message(&self, user_id: UserId, text: &str);
}

trait SyncMessenger: Messenger + Sync + Send {}
```

It's implementation:

```
pub struct DiscordMessenger {
    discord: Arc<Discord>, // (Discord is Sync and Send already)
}
impl Messenger for DiscordMessenger {
    fn send_message(&self, user_id: UserId, text: &str) {
        self.discord.send_message(user_id, text, false);
    }
}
impl SyncMessenger for DiscordMessenger {}
```

And using it:

```
struct Bot {
    messenger: Arc<SyncMessenger>,
}
impl Bot {
    pub fn new() -> Bot {
        Bot { messenger: Arc::new(DiscordMessenger::new()) }
    }   

    fn messenger(&self) -> Arc<SyncMessenger> {
        self.messenger.clone()
    }
}

struct PingCommand {
    fn fire(&mut self, bot: &mut Bot) {
        bot.messenger().send_message(UserId(0), "Pong");
    }
}
```

Everything worked fine. Now I want to implement `TestMessenger` which does not really send a message through a network but toggles a flag in `Self` instead:

```
#[cfg(test)]
struct TestMessenger {
    pub message_sent: bool,
}
impl Messenger for TestMessenger {
    fn send_message(&mut self, user_id: UserId, text: &str) { // we have `&mut self` here
        self.message_sent = true;
    }
}
```

So I need to change `send_message(&self)` to `send_message(&mut self)` everywhere (in traits and in implementations). I did that but after I can't compile my user code:

```
struct PingCommand {
    fn fire(&mut self, bot: &mut Bot) {
        bot.messenger().send_message(UserId(0), "Pong");
    }
}
```

Gives error:

```
   |
12 |         let _ = bot.messenger().send_message(UserId(0),
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable

error: aborting due to previous error
```

I have found something that works but it looks very ugly to me (and requires `unwrap()` which I would like to avoid):

```
let _ = Arc::get_mut(&mut bot.messenger()).unwrap().send_message(UserId(0),
```

So the question here is how to do that as much simple as possible, without `unwrap()`s, static methods like `Arc::get_mut`? Why simple `fn messenger(&self) -> Arc<SyncMessenger>` is not possible to call `mut` methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that trait methods implemented should be strictly checked for compliance: `send_message(&mut self, user_id: UserId, text: &str)` is not compliant with `send_message(&self, user_id: UserId, text: &str)` due to the former's mutable reference to `self`, and the compiler would eventually complain.

Therefore, interior mutability is required here, so that state changes may happen behind an immutable reference. In this case, since you're dealing with other thread-safe components, you may consider using the thread-safe [`AtomicBool`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicBool.html).

```
use std::sync::atomic::AtomicBool;

#[cfg(test)]
struct TestMessenger {
    pub message_sent: AtomicBool,
}
impl Messenger for TestMessenger {
    fn send_message(&self, user_id: UserId, text: &str) { // we have `&mut self` here
        self.message_sent.store(true, Ordering::AcqRel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use interior mutability to change data behind immutable references.

```
use std::cell::Cell;
struct TestMessenger {
    pub message_sent: Cell<bool>,
}
impl Messenger for TestMessenger {
    fn send_message(&self, user_id: UserId, text: &str) { 
        self.message_sent.set(true);
    }
}
```

This struct is for single-threaded cases. You'll need `std::sync::Mutex` instead of `Cell` to have `Sync` for TestMessenger.